# Read raw USB data for port being used by VirtualBox

Tags: linux, serial-port, usb, virtualbox

I have software for communicating with a serial device that only runs on Windows 7. My host machine is running Ubuntu 16.04, with Windows 7 in virtual box.

I've managed to set it up using USB device filters in VirtualBox settings so that Windows sees and can communicate with the device.

However I'd like to capture what's being sent to and from the device. I thought something as simple as `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` would work but unfortunately when I start VirtualBox I get this in dmesg:

```
[31199.465270] vboxdrv: ffffffffc0df4020 VMMR0.r0
[31199.653494] vboxdrv: ffffffffc0ef7020 VBoxDDR0.r0
[31199.710573] VBoxNetFlt: attached to 'wlp1s0' / 98:54:1b:04:13:48
[31199.863579] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[31199.863674] ftdi_sio 1-3:1.0: device disconnected
```

So I don't know which file to monitor in `/dev` anymore. I suppose I might be able to try listen for the communication from Windows, but if I can I'd like to know if it's possible to monitor it from my host machine.

Edit:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505385/monitoring-sniffing-dev-ttyusb0-created-by-ftdi-usb-serial-converter) answer helped me for a start. I now get some cool looking stream on the terminal, next step is deciphering it, or if anyone has a better way I'm interested - it looks like the person who answered that question still has deciphering it as a TODO :-)

Comment: You could answer your own question if you have found a solution

Comment: I'll see if I can filter out the noise to get just input and output tomorrow. If I can I'll answer this

Comment: @user45891 sort of answered it, but most of the credit goes to the poster of the other answer

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it was communicating with software in VirtualBox didn't really matter. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35505385/monitoring-sniffing-dev-ttyusb0-created-by-ftdi-usb-serial-converter) answer got me most of the way just by (as root):

- `modprobe usbmon`
- `cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices|less` and search for device
- `cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/7u` where 7 is the number from "Bus=" in the device table from step 2

From there is was just filtering the output.

A basic way could be just

`cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/1u |cut -d\  -f9- | grep ^\n`

But the device I was working with was constantly sending lines with just 4 characters, to filter out those I got the [address word](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt) from the output line, and grepped for that. In my case I only wanted to capture "C" or callback output. I was also filtering for lines that contained more than just the default "0160" that the device was constantly outputting. To try understand the hex output I put a `xxd -r -p` at the end which gave me:

`cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/1u | grep -e 'C Bi:1:005:1\s0\s\w*\s=\s0160\w' | cut -d\  -f8- | xxd -r`

Where the grep is 
`grep -e 'C <address> <someotherstuff> = <always-output-string><anycharacter>`

This still gave me this indecipherable junk below, but I don't know the format so I'm stuck here. Maybe the steps to read and filter will be useful for someone

>
O�UDQN��RG_JAMS142E   DEFAULT0XXXXXXX�lSTz:�RSDU�vy��������������������������z�fff=�����{6zC"zÐ�u6zC�z�H
;�����C��Af[���RSC�b ISD�EGIN
�CG_IEW0321:0407JUN12S��Z-�$''$'''C'''